# Plugin interrupted, invalidated errors for custom keyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, keyboard, ios-simulator

All of a sudden, a project that used to run well on iOS simulator no longer works. Whenever I try switching to the custom keyboard, I get two errors:

1) plugin `com.XXX.XXX.KeyBoardName` interrupted

2) plugin `com.XXX.XXX.KeyBoardName` invalidated

I tried resetting the simulator, rebooting `Xcode`, etc. - everything to no avail. Happy to provide more details if helpful!

**Edit:-**
I am using this sample code https://github.com/bjhstudios/iOSCustomKeyboard.

The above sample is working fine. The problem is when I switch the keyboards between native and custom, after some time, I get this error is log and suddenly, custom keyboard disappear. Then, again, I have to go to Simulator Settings and add the custom keyboard.

Comment: @Piyush Dubey can you add more specific information about your project? Hard to diagnose without more info…

Comment: Longshot, but if you used any cocoapods. Have you checked that you have the latest version as well as all pods are updated to latest?

Comment: @PiyushDubey Found the solution. Please check it out :D

Comment: I have added some more information. Please check it.

Comment: @PiyushDubey Where do these additional informations come from? You're not the OP...

Comment: @EricD Yes, I am not the OP. I apologize for adding information. But, I am facing same problem and I have just explained the scenario(more information), as asked by members. Should I remove additional information?

Comment: @PiyushDubey You've added a bounty, so you should probably let it be now. :p But in the future I think it's better to write your own question (and if necessary refer to another one by link) because we don't know if OP here would be ok with this addition - and I feel it's *slightly* off-topic considering the original question (but yeah, no big issue either, just saying).

Comment: @EricD I'll keep this thing in mind. And I think OP would not have any problem because he would have faced the issue and might be waiting for answer. Anyways, thanks for the information. :)

Comment: @PiyushDubey Yes, but you are about to waste a 50 rep bounty unless you award it to someone.

Comment: @Coder1000 Yes, I know about that. But, how I award a bounty, if any answer is not useful to me?

Comment: @Coder1000 Thanks for letting me know about your choice. But, I can go it to waste, if it didn't help me. I appreciate the efforts putting by the person by answering the question, but that's not enough I believe. And I can see why you're asking me to award a bounty, even if that answer didn't work for me or someone else.

Comment: @PiyushDubey It's quite obvious indeed. But I needed to know so I could know if I would delete my answer or not. Have a nice day :)

Comment: @PiyushDubey- Reset simulator then delete Derived data then Can you please write the custom Keyboard switching code on the main thread and then try.it will work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your code, i have faced with this too. Look at my old code

```
let keyboardNib = UINib(nibName: "ChatCustomKeyboardView", bundle: nil)
customKeyboardView = keyboardNib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
view.addSubview(customKeyboardView)
```

Then i changed it to this

```
let nib = UINib(nibName: "ChatCustomKeyboardView", bundle: nil)
let objects = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)
view = objects[0] as! UIView;
```

and everything start working. So try to assign your view but not add as subview.

Comment: I experienced that,
instantiateWithOwner take more time to load nib as our custom keyboard view and app crash before nibbling load..

I used
**let nibViews = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("vwKeyboard", owner: self, options: nil)
        keyboardView = nibViews?.first as! UIView
        keyboardView.frame.size = view.frame.size
        self.view.addSubview(keyboardView)**

It response quicker than nib.instantiateWithOwner